# phpLDAPadmin: managing permissions

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, filtering, openldap, phpldapadmin

I'm developping a LDAP authentification server and I want to provide access to my users to a phpLDAPadmin panel.

Let's say that I have my LDAP with following structure:

> admin ROOT
>
> > Groups
> >
> > > Admin group
> > >
> > > > admin
> > >
> > > New app group
> > >
> > > > user3
>
> Users
>
> > admin,
> >     user1,
> >     user2,
> >     user3,
> >     user4,
> >     user5

What can I do to allow the user3 to login to phpLDAPadmin and only have access to the "New app group" configuration (he's part of) ?

(So that he may be able to create/add new users)

Comment: Write an `access` configuration entry. This is all documented.

Comment: Thanks for the information but is there an option to do this from phpLDAPadmin ?